# Titanium Android - Execute a background task at regular intervals

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to execute a background service in my titanium android app at regular intervals. I can achieve this by using interval service. Following is the code:

```
function startMovieAlertService()
{
    var SECONDS = 1800;
    // every 10 seconds
    var intent = Titanium.Android.createServiceIntent(
    {
        url : 'MovieAlertService.js'
    });
    intent.putExtra('interval', SECONDS * 1000);
    Titanium.Android.startService(intent);
}
```

But this service is closed by android system (or titanium) soon after the app is exited using back button. Now I want that this service executes at regular intervals, without being closed. This service will just check for some new data from web server. And this needs to be executed once per day. Please help me.

Comment: You should probably take a look at Google Cloud Messaging http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html . It's better to let the server tell your app when there's new data instead of the app asking the server if something changed.

Comment: @Marcelo I want to support android versions before 2.3.